# Join on same column multiple times

Tags: sql, oracle

how do I join on the same column multiple times, one of the tables is a configuration table with values and other is the data table.

T1:

```
ID    Seq    Code1     Code2     Code3
 1    001    101        203        305
 1    002    107
 2    001    103
 3    005               213
 4    009                          320
 5    001    101                   314
```

T2 (Config table):

```
Value           Description
 101             Strawberry
 103             Raspberry    
 107             Blueberry
 111             Banana
 203             Cashews
 213             Almonds
 305             Bellpepper
 320             Tomatoes
 314             Potatoes
```

I need to display the code and its relevant description for each ID.

Expected Output:

```
ID       Code1    Description  Code2  Description  Code3 Description
1        101      Strawberry   203    Cashews      305    Bellpepper
1        107      Blueberry
2        103      Raspberry
3                              213     Almonds
4                                                  320     Tomatoes
5        101     Strawberry                        314     Potatoes
```

This is what I have tried so far, however, it is not giving me the desired output:

```
    select distinct ID,code1, T2.description, 
    code2, T2.description, code3, T2.description 
    from T1,T2
    where (T1.Code1=T2.Value OR T1.Code2=T2.Value or T1.Code3=T2.Value)
```

How can I achieve this? Sorry if my question is confusing, I can provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's multiple outer join with the `t2` table:

```
select a.id, a.seq,
  a.code1, d1.description,
  a.code2, d2.description,
  a.code3, d3.description
from t1 a left join t2 d1 on a.code1 = d1.value
          left join t2 d2 on a.code2 = d2.value
          left join t2 d3 on a.code3 = d3.value
order by a.id, a.seq;

   ID SEQ      CODE1 DESCRIPTIO      CODE2 DESCRIPTIO      CODE3 DESCRIPTIO
----- --- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
    1 001        101 Strawberry        203 Cashews           305 Bellpepper
    1 002        107 Blueberry
    2 001        103 Raspberry
    3 005                              213 Almonds
    4 009                                                    320 Tomatoes
    5 001        101 Strawberry                              314 Potatoes
```